# How to manage directory path while developing in windows and testing in linux python api

Tags: python

I am working on python web app which involve few python flask api. I am developing this on windows and have tested all the api using postman. Everything is working fine. In my webapp project, I have to create few directories if they are not present, so for that I am using below code:

```
if not os.path.isdir("dataset/" + client_name):
    # if client name directory is not created, then create it
    client_dir = curr_path + '\\' + 'dataset\\' + client_name 
    os.mkdir(client_dir)
```

I am deploying this webapp on [pythonanywhere.com](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/). This uses linux as it platform and I am using windows for development due to which issues are coming. Now in windows we use `\` for directory but in linux, it uses `/`.

How can I manage this while working on windows and deploy on linux. Is there some kind of config I can define.?

Thanks

Comment: Avoid using slashes in your code all together. Using `os.path.join(...)` to create your paths will format them appropriately for the given system: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.join

Comment: @SyntaxVoid Can you give an example please?

Comment: @SyntaxVoid has one correct way.  There is also `os.path.sep`.  If you do from `pathlib import Path` then `client_dir = Path.cwd() / 'dataset' / client_name`.  `pathlib` uses `/` as the join operator, but it interprets it correctly according to the platform you are on.  Then `client_dir.mkdir()`.

Comment: pretty much what was said.  banish ‘/‘ and ‘\’ from your code.  even ‘os.path.sep’ is usually unnecessary: os.path.join and pathlib do it much better.  be careful around top-level considerations like ‘/‘ vs ‘C:’. The ‘\__file\__’ var, when available (in mains), can be helpful.  remember you can climb **up** with ‘..’.  last: **os.makedirs() **

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can avoid using slashes in your code all together. Construct your paths with `os.path.join`. In the example you posted, all you should have to do is change

```
client_dir = curr_path + '\\' + 'dataset\\' + client_name
```

to

```
client_dir = os.path.join(curr_path, "dataset", client_name)
```

**Edit:** You should also change

```
if not os.path.isdir("dataset/" + client_name):
```

to

```
if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join("dataset", client_name))
```

and the path will be constructed appropriately for whatever system the code is running on.

Comment: os.path.join was a life saver using Windows during the day and Linux at _night_.

Comment: I would also encourage the use of `os.path.sep`.

Comment: `os.path.join` implements `os.sep` under the hood

Answer (score 1):

you can use Path from [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

> This module offers classes representing filesystem paths with semantics appropriate for different operating systems.

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('dataset')/client_name

if not path.isdir():
    client_dir = Path(curr_path)/'dataset'/client_name
    client_dir.mkdir()
```

Comment: Can you provide an example how this solves the problem? Otherwise it should be a comment instead

Comment: @SyntaxVoid yes, sure

Answer (score 1):

Use `Path` from `pathlib`.  `Path` is an alias for `WindowsPath` on Windows and `PosixPath` on Linux/Unix.  This means that when you use the slash operator (`/`) it is interpreted correctly according to the platform:

```
from pathlib import Path

curr_path = Path.cwd() # or something else
client_dir = curr_path / 'dataset' / client_name

if not client_dir.is_dir():
    client_dir.mkdir()
```